# Identity provider between two keycloak servers

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, keycloak, openid-connect

I have the following scenario:
**Keycloak A**
**Keycloak B**

**Keycloak A** is being used in a spring boot application for authentication.

**Keycloak B** is being used in a spring boot application for authentication.

I would like the users (JWT) of Keycloak A to be able to access the endpoint of the application being managed by keycloak B.

What I did and it didn't work:
In keycloak B I created an Identity provider.
*http://localhost:8083/auth/realms/master/broker/oidc/endpoint*

I added the fields with the keycloak A data:

**Authorization URL**

**Token URL**

**Client Authentication** : Client secret sent as post

**Client ID**

**client secret**

In keycloak A I created a client and put the

**Access Type**: confidential

**Valid Redirect URIs**: *http://localhost:8083/auth/realms/master/broker/keycloak-oidc/endpoint*

In Credential I put Client Authenticator and generated the key.

When I generate a token in keycloak A and try to access the endpoints of the application that is in keycloak B, it generates the following error:

```
 Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found
```

What am I forgetting to do?

Comment: I have no experience with keycloak, but it looks like the keys used to sign the JWT doesn't exist on Keycloak B.

Comment: both keycloak are using the same alg: RS256

Comment: Right, but do both use the same key pair to sign/verify the JWT?

Comment: I managed to get this error:
Failed to verify token: Didn't find publicKey for specified kid

So keycloak b doesn't have the public key of keycloak a.

Comment: That answers your question on why you are seeing the error :)
The docs might have some info on how to configure with the public key of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Keycloak instance (or realm) has its own set of keys for signing JWTs, and each can rotate it at its own pace (yes, key pairs should change at runtime, and JWT decoders should fetch a new public key when the one they had is deprecated).

You can't use keys from Keycloak B to validate a token issued by Keycloak A, even if Keycloak A is registered as a federated identity provider in Keycloak B. When a user chooses "login with Keycloak A" when authenticating on Keycloak B, the token received by the client is emitted by Keycloak B.

As a I understand it, your Spring applications are resource servers (it is secured with access tokens).

Spring boot default configuration is single tenant (accepts identities from a single issuer). To change that, you'll have to:

- instantiate two distinct JWT decoders (one for Keycloak A issuer and another
  for Keycloak B issuer)
- provide with a custom authentication manager which delegates to the right decoder based on the `iss` claim (Keycloak A and Keycloak B won't put the same value in the tokens they issue)

Complete sample with just `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` in [this tutorial of mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/servlet-resource-server). But you can achieve the same with no Java conf at all, using `spring-addons-starter-oidc`, a stater of mine which comes on top of Spring Boot "official" starters:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
# spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver properties fit only to single tenant scenarios (only one issuer). It is not used here.

keycloak-a: http://localhost:8442/realms/a
keycloak-b: http://localhost:8442/realms/b

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${keycloak-a}
          username-claim: preferred_username
          authorities:
          # map realm roles to spring authorities (you might add a prefix or case transformation with dedicated properties) 
          - path: $.realm_access.roles
          # map roles for all clients, you might want to restrict to a single client or two
          - path: $.resource_access.*.roles
        - iss: ${keycloak-b}
          username-claim: preferred_username
          authorities:
          - path: $.realm_access.roles
          - path: $.resource_access.*.roles
        resourceserver:
          # What is not listed in "permit-all" requires request to be authorized
          # Fine-tuned access-control with method security ("@preAuthorize" and alike) or a by exposing a ResourceServerExpressionInterceptUrlRegistryPostProcessor bean
          permit-all:
          - "/actuator/health/readiness"
          - "/actuator/health/liveness"
          - "/v3/api-docs/**"
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity()
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

Bootiful, isn't it?

The best part being you don't have anything specific to Keycloak in your code and can switch any of the issuers to whatever OIDC authorization server you like (Auth0, Cognito, etc.) by just editing properties for authorities and username mapping.

Comment: That is the problem:
6.x and 7.X branch are designed for spring-boot 3 and requires JDK 17 as a minimum

Comment: I updated my application to spring boot 3.1.1 and everything worked fine @ch4mp thank you very much again, I will study your repository and try to contribute something.